# How to show related tables in ArcGIS Viewer for Flex v3?

Tags: popup, arcgis-flex-viewer, widget, identify

Is there any way to show related tables's result in ArcGIS viewer for Flex? Like identifying in desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the current version (3.0), but the next version (3.1) will support showing related records.

Update: version 3.1 was released in December 2012 and supports editing related records. This functionality is provided by the RelationshipInspector component which is also part of the AttributeTable and PopUpInfo classes.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/index.html?com/esri/ags/components/RelationshipInspector.html&com/esri/ags/components/class-list.html

Answer (score 2):

3.1 allows viewing and editing of related tables, they have to be in table format and not a layer.